# Create a form dynamically from JSON when a button pressed or set visible to true?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, forms

Apologies for the title, I wasn't sure how to encapsulate my woes in one fell swoop.

I have a simple problem but can't decide on solution or implementation.

I'm creating a web test suite, there is a drop down which presents the user with the options available.  Each of these options is a reference to a specific template / form.

To explain:

Select options: ABC / DEF / GHI.

Selecting ABC will generate a form for the user that has data already populated, they can then submit this form to run the test for it or alter the data and then submit.

Selecting DEF or GHI will generate a similar format but different form, these will have different values etc.

I can't figure out the best route to take, I don't need a great deal of complexity but I'm also looking for elegance, contradiction?

I'm think the easiest solution is to have all forms already populated and on the page but hidden with css, I can then use jquery to make the form visible again, or some combination where maybe I have a blanket div hiding it and then set z index of the one I want visible, not sure but doesn't sound very pretty.

The alternative would require a bit more effort but would involve dynamically creating the form and then presenting it when the button is pressed, potentially from a json object.

Any thoughts / suggestions / advice?

Comment: IMO...if you want the simplest, then "hardcode" and show/hide the forms based on what the user selects. If there's nothing that needs to change as far as the form structure or input values, then this is your best bet. Next question is why you'd even have to show the form at all. Why not just submit the form when the user makes a selection if they aren't changing anything?

Comment: @jonmrich - that's a great point. So, in the case where they'd be happy with pre populated data I can submit immediately, but there will be occasions when this data will be edited and I may need to randomise the values that the fields contain at some point as well.

Answer (score 1):

*They have the same structure.*

*They have different values.*

**Do they have the same `action`?**

- If **yes** then use one form, and change the values when the selection has changed.
- If **no** then up to you, but it's much easier handling one form.

**Do DEF / GHI values change often or are they fixed values?**

- If **yes** they change values often, then get the
  values on `selection change` with a `$.getJSON` and populate the `form` with the correct information, but don't keep the information since they always change.
- If **no**, meaning they are fixed values then on page load get the information with `$.getJSON` (or if previous answer was **no**.. on page load store information in one of the three forms) and store it in a variable. (If previous answer was **yes**) When a `selection change` occurs just get the information from the variable.

Comment: Thanks! The action will ultimatley be going to the same place to build an encrytped string from the values in the form.
Some fields in the form will not be required depending on whether its a ABC or CDE for example.
The odds of the values changing is quite likely as I imagine the testers will want to spam all sorts of variables in as well as using the rpedefined ones I can create

Comment: @SteveGreen depends if you are using a validator plugin or not. Switching the rules for the same form can be relatively easy and should be a walk in a park to handle one form. I recommend sending with the getJSON the rules that go along with each form.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you, do you need something like this (give us an example):

Drop Down Options:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
      <a class="ajax-link" template="my_template_form1" href="#">
        access form1
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="ajax-link" template="my_template_form2" href="#">
        access form2
      </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And load the form template without reload a submit:

```
$('a.ajax-link').click(function (e){
    $("#divMain").load($(this).attr('template'));
});
```

Comment: I think this is inline with what I was considering, I'm now reworking the example to see if I can make it dance and will reply if I have any trouble, thank you for taking the time to reply,. :)